# Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical instead random URL of mobile website is taken

Tags: url, canonical-link

User-declared canonical:

```
https://www.example.com/vijayavani-newspaper-read
```

Google-selected canonical:

```
https://m.example.com/sakshi-newspaper-read
```

I want the Google-selected URL to be same as the user-declared URL.

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before selecting tags.  Using tags that don't apply to your problem is not going to be helpful.